# SQL- Number of times each item is ordered each day

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that is a log of orders with the `itemID` and `orderTime` (in `datetime`). I know I can get the orders of specific items for a specific day like:

```
select 
   itemID, count(itemID) as Sep14 
from 
   tableName
where 
   itemID in (5, 6, 9)
   and orderTime between 'sep 14 2014 00:00:01' and 'sep 14 2014 23:59:59'
group by 
   itemID
```

What I would like to do is get the same results but over a longer time period with results in buckets of days so output would be similar to:

```
itemiD   Sep14   Sep15   Sep16
------   -----   -----   -----
5        0       2       1
6        3       3       0
9        2       1       2
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What db are you using? MySql? Sql Server?

Comment: Please don't use `BETWEEN` and "end" of day like 23:59:59 (since an order could take place at 23:59:59.01). Please read [this](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common.aspx) and [this](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mishandling-date-range-queries.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

```
select itemID, convert(DATE, orderTime), count(*)
from tableName
where itemID in (5, 6, 9)
and (orderTime > 'sep 14 2014 00:00:00' and orderTime < 'sep 21 2014 00:0:00')
group by itemId, convert(DATE, orderTime)
```

This will give you your results one row per day. If you try to get one column per day it's not going to scale.

Comment: I need to run for a specific subset of items and between a specific date range.

Comment: @dotMPEG So add `WHERE` clauses. This does not affect the way the data is grouped, aggregated and returned, except it looks at only the rows you care about. If you need to flip the results sideways, you can use PIVOT (but it will be a pain, because you will need to name the day columns dynamically), or do that in the application / reporting tool (which should be easier).

Comment: I added a where clause to illustrate how you can restrict your results to specific items and dates.

Comment: Getting: "Column 'orderTime' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @dotMPEG With the code in the answer? I doubt it; what did you change?

Answer (score 0):

This will create a dynamic pivot table that will give the output you want. It will create 1 column for each date in the date range for which there is data.  If you want it to include dates with no data, you will need to join it to a calendar table that has all the dates.

```
DECLARE @StartDate date = '20140101'
DECLARE @EndDate date = '20140102'

DECLARE @PivotColumnHeaders varchar(MAX)
SELECT @PivotColumnHeaders =
  COALESCE(
    @PivotColumnHeaders + ',[' + CONVERT(varchar(10),uc.orderTime,110) + ']',
    '[' + CONVERT(varchar(10),uc.orderTime,110) + ']'
  )
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT orderTime  FROM tablename WHERE orderTime BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate) UC

DECLARE @PQuery varchar(MAX) = '
SELECT * FROM (SELECT ID, CAST(orderTime as date), Value FROM tablename T0 WHERE CAST(OrderTime as date) BETWEEN ''' + CONVERT(varchar(10),@StartDate,110) + ''' AND ''' + CONVERT(varchar(10),@EndDate,110) +''') T1
PIVOT (COUNT([Value]) FOR CAST(orderTime as date) IN (' + @PivotColumnHeaders + ') ) AS P'
EXECUTE (@PQuery)
```